# POD type initialization using initialization list does not work

Tags: c++

I have defined a POD type as below:

```
template<typename kernelEntryT, size_t kernelRowSize, size_t kernelColSize>
class ImageProcessing::Kernel {
    kernelEntryT kernelMatrix[kernelRowSize][kernelColSize];
};

int main(){
    ImageProcessing::Kernel<int,3,3> k = {{0,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,0}};
}
```

It does not compile, and tell me:

```
error: could not convert ‘{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘ImageProcessing::Kernel<int, 3ul, 3ul>’
     ImageProcessing::Kernel<int,3,3> k = {{0,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,0}};
```

---

Edit: [Test Code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f1c7c098a13e7bbf)

Comment: It looks like you need an extra set of braces: `ImageProcessing::Kernel<int,3,3> k = {{{0,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,0}}};`

Comment: @juanchopanza Still not working...

Comment: does the matrix entry element have a constructor that takes an int as an argument?

Comment: @tomislav-maric ugh its an integer.

Comment: (headbang) yes. I see.

Comment: `kernelMatrix` is private. If you add an additional pair of braces and make it public it works.

Comment: @Simple Solution is just as as your name! *facepalm* Stupid mistakes

Comment: I wasn't sure if you had intended for the member to be private in your example, or if you had omitted the `public` in the process of simplifying it. It is best to post self-contained code that reproduces the error you're trying to fix in the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a missing set of braces (the data member is a single array) and you need to make the data member public, because an aggregate cannot have private or protected members.

This is a simplified, working example:

```
#include <cstddef> // for std::size_t

template<typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t M>
class Kernel {
 public:
    T kernelMatrix[N][M];
};

int main(){
    Kernel<int,3,3> k = { {{0,0,0}, {0,1,0}, {0,0,0}} };
}
```

Comment: I get the following error for this: /vtmp/tmp/ccX1uxVt.o:(.eh_frame+0x12): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status. Using gcc-4.3 with compilation flag -std=c++0x. Do I require gcc 4.7?

Comment: @SimonBosley Well, that's a linker error, and there's no way I would be able to reproduce that. For one, there isn't anything called "personality" in this code.

Comment: Maybe my linker thinks it has a personality, I for one am not laughing :-P

Comment: @SimonBosley Well, this code doesn't even require C++11 compliance, so you could drop the `c++0x` flag and see. I compiled with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors -O3`.

Comment: oh yeah in my search to find a compiler that supported the unnecessary c++0x std was the problem. Works fine with gcc 3.4.2 that's set-up correctly on my machine. I was thinking about newer initialization list features, but of course initializing an array has been around since the C days. Cheers!